How to find an exact solution for $X=X^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ satisfying $AX=XA^T$ and $B=XC^T$
Assuming that I know that the following pair of equations has an exact solution:
$$\exists X=X^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}: AX=XA^T,\ B=XC^T$$
For some matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $X$ is invertible. How do I find $X$?
Obviously I can just form the following overdetermined system:
$$\begin{bmatrix} I \otimes A - A \otimes I \\ C \otimes I \end{bmatrix} vect(X)=vect(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ B \end{bmatrix})$$
And solve it only for the elements of $vect(X)$ corresponding to the upper-triangular elements of $X$.
This works fine in practice, but I can't help but think that since an exact solution exists it should be possible to solve for $X$ without solving an overdetermined least-squares problem?
For a bit of context, in my particular application $X$ is the matrix associated with a reciprocal State-Space realization, such that:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \dot x(t) \\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ u(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} XA^TX^{-1} & XC^T \\ B^TX^{-1} & D^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ u(t) \end{bmatrix} $$
Which ensures that (and always exists when) the transfer-function $H(s)=H^T(s)$ is symmetric.
This problem appears regularly in the control literature, but so far I have not come across any explicit solution, perhaps because it is such a 'trivial' problem that the authors don't care to explain how to solve it.
EDIT:
Let's take a look at the case when $n=2$ and $m=1$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
I \otimes A - A \otimes I \\ C \otimes I
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} \\ x_{21} \\ x_{12} \\ x_{22}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_{12} & -a_{12} & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} - a_{11} & 0 & -a_{12} \\
-a_{21} & 0 & a_{11} - a_{22} & a_{12} \\
0 & -a_{21} & a_{21} & 0 \\
\hline
c_{11} & 0 & c_{12} & 0 \\
0 & c_{11} & 0 & c_{12}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} \\ x_{21} \\ x_{12} \\ x_{22}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \hline b_{11} \\ b_{21}
\end{bmatrix}$$
After eliminating the variable $x_{12} = x_{21}$ we get:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} - a_{11} & -a_{12} \\
-a_{21} & a_{11} - a_{22} & a_{12} \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
c_{11} & c_{12} & 0 \\
0 & c_{11} & c_{12}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} \\ x_{21} \\ x_{22}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \hline b_{11} \\ b_{21}
\end{bmatrix}$$
The two rows corresponding to the diagonal elements of the top matrix on the right hand side are both zero, and in addition to that the two rows corresponding to the off diagonal elements of the top RHS matrix are the negative of each other. Eliminating zero and (negative) duplicate rows we get:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{22} - a_{11} & -a_{12} \\
\hline
c_{11} & c_{12} & 0 \\
0 & c_{11} & c_{12}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} \\ x_{21} \\ x_{22}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ \hline b_{11} \\ b_{21}
\end{bmatrix}$$
In turns out that eliminating zero and redundant rows from the LHS matrix results in a matrix with $(n^2-n)/2+nm$ rows and still $(n^2-n)/2+n$ columns, which happens to be a square matrix in this case where $m=1$.

is $B$ full rank?

@Exodd That is not guaranteed, but usually $m<n$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ has full column-rank

@Exodd The only thing that can be safely assumed is that $X$ exists and is real-symmetric and invertible.

Note that $AX = XA^T$ with $X$ invertible is equivalent to $X^{-1}AX = A^T$. Consequently, we can find $X$ using something like the diagonalizations, Jordan normal forms, or Frobenius normal forms of $A$ and $A^T$.

This MO post is relevant

@BenGrossmann I am pretty sure that the extra condition on $X$, I.e. $XB=C$ is not redundant in general. So the problem is not just to find $AX=XA^T$ for which I believe that $X$ is not unique in general, but to find instead the unique solution which also satisfies $XB=C$

@user9413641 You're right. But at the very least, we could parameterize the solutions to $X^{-1}AX = A^T$ and plug those into the equation $XB = C$. This is all relatively easy in the case that $A$ is diagonalizable with distinct eigenvalues, which is in a sense the "most common" case.

@BenGrossmann In my application $A$ will often not have distinct eigen-values, and is also not guaranteed to be diagonalizable, yet a solution is guaranteed to exist.

@BenGrossmann I have added a bit of context, perhaps it helps. My particular application is finding the matrix associated with a 'reciprocal' State-Space realization. Therefore the eigen-values of $A$ are the poles of the system and there is no guarantee that they are unique or that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Long time not done anything in control, so take the comment with a grain of salt. I think the state space representation needs to be minimal for it to have any chance of working. And also, since $X$ is a change of basis, there is no reason for it to be symmetric: think about a second order SISO system.

Shouldn't the dimensions be $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and/or some of the equations should have a $C^\top$ instead of $C$?

@KwinvanderVeen Yes to comply with the standard control literature it should, the second equation should actually be $B=XC^T$ with $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, but when I first wrote the question I just wrote it as a general math-question and not necessarily linked to control, so I just opted to drop the transpose and defined $B,C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $XB=C$, it was just to not confuse the audience.

@user9413641 to keep the notation consistent please then update the equation of the 'reciprocal' State-Space realization.

@KwinvanderVeen I have edited the question so that it is now $B=XC^T$ and the shape of $C$ as well

In order to obtain a well conditioned equation I will assume that the state space model is minimal, so $(A,B)$ is controllable and $(A,C)$ is observable.
Given is (minimal) state space model
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= A\,x(t) + B\,u(t), \\
y(t) &= C\,x(t) + D\,u(t),
\end{align}
\right. \tag{1}
\label{ss1}
$$
with corresponding transfer function $H(s) = C\,(s\,I-A)^{-1} B + D$. For this transfer function it is given that it is symmetric, $H(s) = H^\top(s) = B^\top\,(s\,I-A^\top)^{-1} C^\top + D^\top$. Note that this always holds for single-input-single-output systems. Since the system $(A,B,C,D)$ from \eqref{ss1} is similar (has the same transfer function associated with it), given that the transfer function is symmetric, to the system $(A^\top,C^\top,B^\top,D^\top)$
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\dot{z}(t) &= A^\top z(t) + C^\top u(t), \\
y(t) &= B^\top z(t) + D^\top u(t),
\end{align}
\right. \tag{2}
\label{ss2}
$$
therefore \eqref{ss1} and \eqref{ss2} are related to each other via a similarity transformation $x(t) = X\,z(t)$, such that
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
A^\top &= X^{-1} A\,X, \\
C^\top &= X^{-1} B, \\
B^\top &= C\,X.
\end{align}
\right. \tag{3}
\label{transform}
$$
Given the controllability matrix of $(A,B)$ for \eqref{ss1} and $(A^\top,C^\top)$ for \eqref{ss2}
$$
\mathcal{C}_1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
B & A\,B & \cdots & A^{n-1} B
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
\mathcal{C}_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
C^\top & A^\top C^\top & \cdots & (A^\top)^{n-1} C^\top
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and observability matrix of $(A,C)$ for \eqref{ss1} and $(A^\top,B^\top)$ for \eqref{ss2}
$$
\mathcal{O}_1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
C \\ C\,A \\ \vdots \\ C\,A^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
\mathcal{O}_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
B^\top \\ B^\top A^\top \\ \vdots \\ B^\top (A^\top)^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
it can be noted that $\mathcal{C}_1 = \mathcal{O}_2^\top$ and $\mathcal{O}_1 = \mathcal{C}_2^\top$. Using \eqref{transform} $\mathcal{C}_2$ and $\mathcal{O}_2$ can also be written as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}_2 &=
\begin{bmatrix}
X^{-1} B & X^{-1} A\,X\,X^{-1} B & \cdots & (X^{-1} A\,X)^{n-1} X^{-1} B
\end{bmatrix}, \\ 
&= X^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
B & A\,B & \cdots & A^{n-1} B
\end{bmatrix}, \\
&= X^{-1}\,\mathcal{C}_1,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathcal{O}_2 &=
\begin{bmatrix}
C\,X \\ C\,X\,X^{-1} A\,X \\ \vdots \\ C\,X\,(X^{-1} A\,X)^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}, \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
C \\ C\,A \\ \vdots \\ C\,A^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} X, \\
&= \mathcal{O}_1\,X.
\end{align}
Both of these are equivalent to $\mathcal{C}_1^\top = \mathcal{O}_1\,X$. It can be noted that for $m>1$ this is also an overdetermined system of equations, but a unique solution can be obtained using
$$
X = (\mathcal{O}_1^\top \mathcal{O}_1)^{-1} \mathcal{O}_1^\top \mathcal{C}_1^\top. \tag{4} \label{X}
$$
The property $X=X^\top$ has not been used here, but this should hold for the obtained solution (up to numerical accuracy when calculated numerically). If \eqref{X} does not satisfy $X=X^\top$ then most likely the associated transfer function is not symmetric.

It can be noted that a non-overdetermined system of equations can be obtained using the controllability and observability Gramian
$$
W_c(t) = \int_0^t e^{A\,\tau} B\,B^\top e^{A^\top \tau} d\tau,
$$
$$
W_o(t) = \int_0^t e^{A^\top \tau} C^\top C e^{A\,\tau} d\tau,
$$
which under the similarity transformation can be shown to be related to each other according to $W_c(t) = X\,W_o(t)\,X$. However, solving this does not yields a unique solution and most of its solutions do not satisfy \eqref{transform}.

Great answer, and very interesting insight you provided about the similarities of the controllabilty and observability matrices, thanks a lot. But at the end of the day this solution seems to me like it would be computationally inferior to my own solution, since you would have to compute the ctrl/obsv matrices and you end up with a system with more rows and columns, any thoughts on that?

I will definitely have to try it out

@user9413641 my approach does indeed require calculating the controllability and observability matrices, which are $\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n,m}$ and $\in\mathbb{R}^{n,m\times n}$ respectively, but the resulting matrix inverse is only taken of matrix of size $n\times n$. However, your Kronecker product approach involves a matrix of size $n(n+m)\times n^2$, so after applying the symmetry constraint the least squares solution would still involve inverting a matrix of size $n(n+1)/2\times n(n+1)/2$.

@user9413641 a small side note that is relevant to both our solutions is that one could also include a positive definite weighting matrix (which could for example help the conditioning of the matrix that has to be inverted).

Right good point I overlooked that detail, I will definitely try it.

Just drop for now the constraint that $X$ should be symmetric and consider the equation $AX-XA^T=0$. This is a Sylvester equation and the solution is unique if and only if $A$ and $A^*$ do not share any eigenvalue.
This means that all eigenvalues would need to be non-real. However, that would imply that the only solution would be zero. So, we do not want that. This means that a necessary condition for your problem to be solvable with a non-zero $X$ is that $A$ has at least one real eigenvalue.
That said, one can vectorize the problem while taking the symmetric structure of the matrix $X$ into account. To this aim, define $\mathrm{vec}(\cdot)$ to be the usual vectorization operator and by $\overline{\mathrm{vec}}(\cdot)$ the reduced vectorization operator given by
$\overline{\mathrm{vec}}(X)$ is given by
\begin{equation}
    \left[\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccc}
      X_{11} & \sqrt{2}X_{21} & \ldots & \sqrt{2}X_{n1} & | & X_{22} & \sqrt{2}X_{32} & \ldots & \sqrt{2}X_{n2} & | & \ldots & | & X_{nn}.
    \end{array}\right].
  \end{equation}
One can relate those quantities for a symmetric matrix $X$ as
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{vec}(X)=F\overline{\mathrm{vec}}(X)
  \end{equation}
where $F\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n(n+1)/2}$, $F^{T}F=I$. This is a standard way of dealing with symmetric matrices using vectorization operators.
Using those operators, we get
$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}F^T(I \otimes A - A \otimes I)F \\ F^T(C \otimes I)F \end{bmatrix}}_{\mbox{$M$}}\overline{\mathrm{vec}}(X)=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \overline{\mathrm{vec}}(B) \end{bmatrix}}_{\mbox{$b$}}.
$$
You can now use any method for solving that linear system of equation. For instance, there will be a solution if and only if $b\in \mathrm{span}(M)$ and when this is the case all solutions are given by
$$
\overline{\mathrm{vec}}(X)=M^+b+(I-M^+M)z
$$
where $M^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $M$ and $z$ is an arbitrary vector.

I am working on a matrix solution to that problem. This will take some time. In the meantime, I am happy to address some comments and questions.
